AWS EMR - Output from print statement in pyspark job not present in log files
I am running a pyspark job in Amazon EMR cluster in client mode.
I have added few print statements to do some debugging, but I am not able to see the output generated from print statements in job logs.
I have checked both stdout.gz and stderr.gz files generated but did not find the output generated by print statements.
I have also tried to find the print statements using solutions given in these links link1 and link2 , but nothing seems to be working.
Can someone help me find out where can I see the output of print statements generated by pyspark job?
